# Apache rewrite merge rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Earlier the admin RewriteRule was effecting *scripts/admin.js* until I added the RewriteCond.

Then I noticed that *scripts/members.js* was being effected by the same rule with the member context.

I added the exact same RewriteCond after as is below...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|zip)$
RewriteRule .*/admin(.+) admin$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|zip)$
RewriteRule .*/members(.+) members$1 [QSA]
```

Instead of having to manually add a RewriteCond every time to deal with issues how can I merge these rules please?

```
RewriteRule .*/admin(.+) admin$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .*/blog(.+) blog$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .*/forums(.+) forums$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge your three checks into one like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|zip)$
RewriteRule .*/(admin|blog|forms)(.+) $1$2 [QSA]
```

But it does seem like a rule to simply stop processing for js/css files will be a better option for you, unless you actually need rules applied to them for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like it should work though after trying it out and readjusting things for about 20 minutes it's simply not working for some reason. I've commented out all the other code too just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert the condition and make a pass-through rule that essentially tells mod_rewrite to stop. This way, you have 1 RewriteCond, 1 extra RewriteRule that is applied via the condition, and then everything else:

```
# Just one of these, note that there is no !
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|zip)$
# pass through, if the request is for a css/js/zip, stop rewriting
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# otherwise, do some rewriting
RewriteRule .*/admin(.+) admin$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .*/blog(.+) blog$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule .*/forums(.+) forums$1 [QSA]
```

This will, however, affect any other rules you have that could apply to requests to css/js/zip, because this will cause all requests for those extensions to bypass all rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately after testing only the specific issue I mentioned nothing changed.